# Using @Stateless session bean to persist 2 entities in one to many relationship

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa, jta, session-bean

Hello I am using 2 @Stateless session beans ClientFacade and CreditCardFacade and I would like to persist both entities using this facades and I would like also to associate Client with CreditCard.

Client is here @OneToMany (inverse side) and CreditCard is @ManyToOne (owning side)

I have written unit test:

```
 Client client = new Client("Credit card owner.");
    client = clientFacade.create(client);

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.add(Calendar.YEAR, 1);

    // create instance of CreditCard
    CreditCard creditCard = new CreditCard(client, "4129239494949494", cal.getTime(), "First Last", CreditCardType.VISA );
    creditCard = cardFacade.create(creditCard);

    clientFacade.refresh(client);
    assertNotNull("Should assign new Credit Card to existing Client.", client.getCreditCards());
    assertTrue(client.getCreditCards().contains(creditCard));

    cardFacade.remove(creditCard);
    assertTrue(cardFacade.count() == 0);
    assertNull(cardFacade.find(new CreditCardId(client.getClientId(), "4129239494949494", cal.getTime())));

    clientFacade.remove(client);
```

But the problem here is that the client, and creditCard is persisted in DB and creditCard has set Foreign Key to client, 
BUT when I'm trying to access client.getCreditCards() it is null despite the fact that there is such relationship in database, and despite I have been refreshing client entity earlier. 
If this was made analogically in RESOURCE_LOCAL instead of JTA such approach works perfectly well.

UPDATED

I have modified entities this way:

```
public void setClient(Client client) {
        this.client = client;
        if(!client.getCreditCards().contains(this)) {
            client.getCreditCards().add(this);
        }
    }
```

and:

```
public void addCreditCard(CreditCard creditCard) {
        this.creditCards.add(creditCard);
        if(creditCard.getClient() != this) {
            creditCard.setClient(this);
        }
    }
```

And now trying to persist similar way as above (without) refreshing I'm getting such exception:

```
javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: pl.salonea.entities.Client
```

I consider how I can use such Facade EJB in combination in order to persist relationships. If I'm persisting this relationship in single transaction using EntityTransaction everything seems to persist correctly. But trying to persist with EJB @Stateless using AbstractFacade pattern fails. I can not resolve this issue why I can save this in such a way. Maybe It is caused because I have 2 separate transactions and between them objects are getting detached.

Comment: Is your test `@Transactional`? If not, then the operations will not be happening within the same transaction, and the objects will become detached.

Comment: It isn't  \@Transactonal, adding  \@Transactional doesn't work with Junit Arquillian  \@Test.  I have  \@Inject UserTransaction and i one transaction it now passed the test. But I don't understand this its stupid to use 1 transaction in order to create and delete object. I would like firstly create client... next after some time create for it credit cards and later on delete firstly cards and some time later also this client... remove() method have even em.merge() before em.remove()!